# USB Mouse stutters periodically

Tags: usb, mouse

I'm using an HP dv6000 (not sure of exact model) with a pretty basic Logitech wireless laptop mouse. From time to time, the USB mouse will be very stuttery and less responsive. Not all clicks register and the motion is not smooth. It seems like it's related to the notify-osd coming up when I get an IM or Email or whatever else, but it happens other times as well.

It's not the whole computer becoming less responsive, because if I use the touch pad during one of these fits, it works perfectly smooth. I've replaced the batteries in the mouse and have tried different USB ports with better line of sight, etc. I can't figure out what's going on. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you see anything in `dmesg` when that happens?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear that anything is output in dmesg.

Comment: umm, sometimes my MS mouse acts weird, the pointer shakes, even when the mouse is steady, and sometimes it jumps from one corner of the screen to the opposite. Need answers too.

Comment: @KaustubhP: I've seen that happen with laser mice on a surface that works poorly for them.  Put a pad of paper under and if that behavior stops, get a mousepad or something that works for that.

Answer (score 2):

Other than those points already mentioned, check that the USB cable of the receiver isn't running close to a power cable.  Some of the cheap ones can be affected by interference.

Second have a look in the LED hole of the mouse.  I had a similar issue recently and it was down to a small piece of fluff in the hole.

Answer (score 2):

So, REALLY dumb answer that has gotten me before: make sure there isn't a hard to see piece of lint or dust jammed into the little cavity with the mouse's laser eye.  In some rare cases I've seen the cursor stop moving or even jitter across the screen by itself because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your mouse. (After you have done some additional ruling out to make sure you are absolutely certain).

I've had about two logitech mice do this when they got old. I thought at first it was software related until I tried other mice and the same troublesome mice on windows.

In my experience it's a standard problem with USB mice from Logitech. Appears to happen after they get dust or something in them, and they are rather hard to clean so best to get a cheap mouse and replace it.

Comment: I'll have to test the mouse on a couple different computers and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: How old were yours?  I've had 3 Logitech mice; one got broke through my own fault. The other two still work great: a 10yo wireless trackball and a 5yo wired laser mouse.

Comment: @FredNurk: mine was only about a year old, but it happens with some mice after heavy usage (I used that one quite a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Before you try the above - is your mouse fully charged? (If rechargable) or do you have fresh batteries? It's always been the case for me when my wireless mouse has done what yours is doing.

Comment: He said he already tried replacing the batteries.